# Das Zeugnis, das Ereignis, das Ergebnis aber... die Erlaubnis?

Tags: gender, suffix

Could anyone (a German native speaker at best) explain in a simple way to me why the following nouns have the neutral definite article *das*:

> das Ereignis
>   das Zeugnis
>   das Ergebnis

… but the following noun has *die*?

> die Erlaubnis

Comment: There are more nouns with suffix *-nis* that are female, for example *Erkenntnis*, *Verdammnis*. [Canoonet.eu](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/nis.html?country=D) has an overview on the *-nis* suffix that might be of interest, although it doesn't answer the *Why?*.

Comment: Often German native speakers aren't the best to ask. They don't learn rules, they just learn the language. People that actually studied German are often better qualified to answer such questions

Comment: The rule that nouns with the same endings have the same gender is a life-saver, so the fact that -nis is an exception is painful. Fortunately, nearly all the most common -nis words are das. The only common exceptions are die Erkenntnis and die Erlaubnis; after that they get very obscure (e.g. die Verdammnis).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus#Genus_von_Objekten_ohne_nat%C3%BCrliches_Geschlecht) zitiert eine nicht mehr existierende Duden-Webseite:

> Verb-Ableitungen auf -nis sind nie maskulin. Ob sie im Einzelfall feminin oder neutral sind, folgt keiner festen Regel. Es gibt jedoch eine Tendenz: Bezeichnet das Wort einen durch die Handlung am Verbobjekt eingetretenen Zustand (die …nis = die …theit, z. B. Befugnis, Bekümmernis, Besorgnis), so sind sie meist feminin; steht dagegen die aktuelle Handlung im Vordergrund (das …nis = das …en, z. B. Begräbnis, Bekenntnis, Ergebnis) oder sind beide Deutungen möglich (z. B. Ereignis, Erfordernis, Verständnis), so sind sie eher neutral. Neuere Bildungen sind in der Regel neutral.

[Ein Artikel](https://www.fachportal-paedagogik.de/literatur/vollanzeige.html?FId=431334#vollanzeige) in einer Fachzeitschrift für Deutsch als Fremdsprache kommt nach der Durchsicht der betreffenden Substantive zu dem Schluss:

> Zwar kann man zwei Untergruppen mit dem Artikel *das* identifizieren, aber eine brauchbare Regel fuer eine klare Zuordnung der etwa 30 Nomen mit *das* und der etwa 15 Nomen mit *die* kann nicht aufgestellt werden.

Andere Quellen sagen ähnliches.

**Es gibt keine klare Regel, und du musst das Genus einfach lernen.**

Comment: Da die eingehende Frage auf Englisch war, füge deiner Antwort doch bitte auch noch eine englische Version hinzu

Comment: The Duden-Webpage can still be still found via [archive.org's Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212011049/http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/substantive-auf-nis)

Comment: @infinitezero Deutsch ist vollkommen in Ordnung. :)

Comment: @Jagger Es mag für Dich in Ordnung sein, aber andere Leute die auf englisch suchen und auf diese Frage stoßen, können mit der deutschen Antwort vielleicht nichts anfangen. Deswegen gilt die Faustregel: Immer in der Sprache antworten, in der auch die Frage steht.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus#Genus_von_Objekten_ohne_nat%C3%BCrliches_Geschlecht) cites from a Duden website, that no longer exists:

> verb productions ending on -*nis* are never male. Whether they are female or neuter, does not follow a strict rule. Yet there is a tendency: if the word refers to a condition of the direct object caused by the action (...*nis* analoguous to ...*theit*, as in *Befugnis*, *Bekümmernis*, *Besorgnis*), then those are chiefly female; if on the other hand, the focus is on the action (...*nis* in line with ...*en*, as in *Begräbnis*, *Bekenntnis*, *Ergebnis*) or in cases where both interpretations are valid (eg. *Ereignis*, *Erfordernis*, *Verständnis*), they tend to be neuter. Neologisms are mostly neuter, too.

[An article](https://www.fachportal-paedagogik.de/literatur/vollanzeige.html?FId=431334#vollanzeige) in a journal on German as a foreign language discusses the nouns concerned, concluding:

> while it is possible to identify two subgroups taking the *das* article, no useful rule to clearly assign the ~30 *das* and ~15 *die* nouns to either group can be found.

Other sources largely agree.

**There is no clear-cut rule, you need to learn the article with each word.**

Comment: I did an english version, but the system refused the edit, stating it would change too much. so I posted it as a separate answer, feel free to delete or merge as you see fit.